# How to set code review in gerrit via Gerrit-python-api package?

Tags: python, gerrit, python-gerrit-api

Link to the documentation of the package(Python-gerrit-api):

https://python-gerrit-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Can I set code review like this ssh query

("gerrit review  --code-review +2 --verified +1 --submit")

with this package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set_review function of the Python-gerrit-api package can be used for adding labels like verified +1 and code-review +2.

Link for the above function:

https://python-gerrit-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gerrit.changes.revision.html?highlight=review#gerrit.changes.revision.Revision.set_review